# Javascript sum form fields with decimal values

Tags: javascript

I have a function that sums a bunch of total fields on a page. It could be one field or many. The number could be different every time. It is working correctly but not summing the two decimal places.

So for this list of numbers:

312.69 
39.00

It outputs 351 instead of 351.69

Any ideas why this is based on the following code?

```
settotal() {
this.totalTarget.value = Number(this.qtyTarget.value * this.costTarget.value).toFixed(2)
var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
var tot=0;
var totf=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        totf = (Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

}
document.getElementById('invoice_net_amount').value = totf;
```

}

Comment: `parseInt` makes an integer. you could use an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) instead.

Comment: Or parseFloat()

Comment: Also, `(Math.round(tot * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)` can just be `tot.toFixed(2)`. `.toFixed()` does rounding.